# Does AVR-GCC properly work with 16-bit AVR I/O registers?

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

#### Preamble

It's known that for atomic and simultaneous reading/writing high and low part of 16-bit I/O registers (timer-counters, ICR/OCR, ADC...) AVR uses a shadow temporary register. E.g. reading `TCNT1` on ATmega8:

```
uint8_t tl, th;
tl = TCNT1L;   // tl <- TCNT1L, avr_temp <- TCNT1H (atomic)
th = TCNT1H;   // th <- avr_temp
```

(Here `avr_temp` is the AVR temporary shadow register). So, it's wrong to read `TCNT1H` first, for example.

#### Question

Is it safe to use AVR-GCC with the code like the following?

```
uint16_t ticks;
ticks = TCNT1;
TCNT1 = 0x1234;
```

Will AVR-GCC always generate proper code for these operations?

(It seems to be "no" (how GCC knows that accessing to memory pointed by `TCNT1` uses AVR shadow register?), but avr-libc define macro TCNT1 as well as TCNT1H, TCNT1L and [avr-libc' FAQ](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_16bitio) recommend to directly use `TCNT1`. I'm confused.)

I tested AVR-GCC v4.7.2, and it seems to generate correct code always. Even if I write 'TCNT1 |= 1' it produce proper code with `-O3`:

```
$ avr-gcc -std=c99 -mmcu=atmega8 -S -O3 -o - 1.c
...
in r24,0x2c     // TCNT1L
in r25,0x2c+1   // TCNT1H
ori r24,1
out 0x2c+1,r25
out 0x2c,r24
...
```

The code is the same even if I change `TCNT1` with an ordinary 16-bit variable. So, "how does GCC know that accessing memory pointed by `TCNT1` uses the AVR shadow register?" -- it seems by default to suppose the shadow register *always* when accessing *any* 16-bit variable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how it knows, but I've used `TCNT1` directly in dozens of programs without issue. The [FAQ you linked](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_16bitio) suggests you do it that way, as does every tutorial I've read.

The point the FAQ is making is to assure an interrupt can't happen between the writing of the two registers. Though avr-gcc will generate code that accesses them in the correct order, it can't guarantee an interrupt won't happen between them: you must take care of that.

Comment: Does the downvoter care to say what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: For me, the *"it worked for me without issue"* doesn't tell whether it just worket by accident or by design. Basically, you cannot reverse-engineer language or compiler specification from generated code.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the source of e.g. /usr/lib/avr/include/avr/iom32u4.h you'll see this:

```
#define TCNT1 _SFR_MEM16(0x84)
```

expanding the _SFR_MEM16 macro in /usr/lib/avr/include/avr/sfr_defs.h you  see this:

```
#define _SFR_MEM16(mem_addr) _MMIO_WORD(mem_addr)
```

expanding _MMIO_WORD:

```
#define _MMIO_WORD(mem_addr) (*(volatile uint16_t *)(mem_addr))
```

Then looking at stdint.h:
    typedef unsigned int uint16_t;

Here is where the compiler steps in.  The int type on the AVR platform is 16 bits, and the registers on the AVR are 8, so the compiler must make 2 memory accesses (there are no 16-bit memory access instructions defined for it to use).  As per the documentation [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__sfr.html):

> The compiler will choose the correct instruction sequence to generate based on the address of the register being accessed.

---

As an aside, I first thought it was [variable attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Variable-Attributes.html#AVR-Variable-Attributes), but it turns out it's baked in to the AVR architecture by the memory map of the chip.

Comment: That's not correct; avr-gcc **does not check addresses**.  And checking addresses would not work for indirect accesses, except you would instrument the code or check addresses at run time.

Comment: Citation needed.  I linked directly to the sentence in the AVR-LIbC documentation which says that.

Comment: See [`./gcc/config/avr/avr.cc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/avr/avr.cc;h=4ed390e4cf9ec39c97c2dc67da48defa5dcf4f3e;hb=HEAD) in the AVR backend of GCC. Search for `mem_volatile_p` and read the functions that are using it, it's the functions that are outputting HImode move and load / store instructions. A read from a 16-bit register can still get trashed if an ISR is executed during access, and the ISR is also accessing that same 16-bit SFR. The compiler is not suposed to fix that; if such situation occurs you have to make the access atomic.

Comment: ..apart from that, I don't exactly understand what AVR-LibC documentation is supposed to mean.  **Of course will the compiler generate correct code.** Maybe they mean is that the compiler will use `IN` and `OUT` etc. if possible for address is in the range `__AVR_SFR_OFFSET` ... `__AVR_SFR_OFFSET+0x3f` at compile time, resp. the lower I/O addresses with `SBIC` etc., and use `LD*` and `ST*` if the address has not that form.

Answer (score 0):

> how does GCC know that accessing memory pointed by `TCNT1` uses the AVR shadow register?

avr-gcc won't check for different SFR addresses (as claimed in some other answer).  The trigger is the `volatile` 2-byte access:

Volatile accesses to 2-byte locations will treat *every* access as if it had a shadow register or as if it triggered 2-instruction atomic access like writing `SP` on Xmega.  Fortunately, AVR hardware is consistent over different mult-byte SFRs.

In GCC source at `./gcc/config/avr/avr.c[c]` you will find comments (and code) like:

```
  /* "volatile" forces reading low byte first, even if less efficient,
     for correct operation with 16-bit I/O registers.  */
```

and:

```
  /* "volatile" forces writing high-byte first (no-xmega) resp.
     low-byte first (xmega) even if less efficient, for correct
     operation with 16-bit I/O registers.  */
```

Hence 2-byte access will work as expected.

Notice however, that you still need explicit atomic code if both application code and ISR code are accessing the same 16-bit shadow register, for example with `<util/atomic.h>` from AVR-LibC:

```cpp
#include <util/atomic.h>

uint16_t get_TCNT1 (void)
{
    ATOMIC_BLOCK (ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE)
    {
        return TCNT1;
    }
}
```