# Shifting right a negative number

Tags: c, avr, bit-shift, avr-gcc, twos-complement

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
int main()
{           
  DDRB|=0x82;
  DDRC=0x00;
  DDRD=0xFF;
  TCNT1H=(-640)>>8;
  TCNT1L=(-640);
  TCCR1A=0X00;
  TCCR1B=0X01;
  TIMSK=(1<<TOIE0)|(1<<TOIE1)
  sei();
  PORTD=PINC;
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
  TCNT1H=(-640)>>8;
  TCNT1L=(-640);
  PORTB^=0X80;
}
```

Please help me out with `TCNT1H=(-640)>>8;  TCNT1L=(-640);` code....it's really confusing as I have been using values from 0-256....

Comment: Instead of `TCNT1H` and `TCNT1L` you can [just use `TCNT1`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161918/does-avr-gcc-properly-works-with-16-bit-avr-i-o-registers).

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) and [bit shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts).

In the code above, -640 is just a fancy <s>(and unintuitive)</s> way of writing the bit pattern `1111 1101 1000 0000` while the `>>8` part is a frequently used idiom for cutting off the lower 8 bits.

---

It's probably not the cleanest way of setting the AVR timer registers in C since at least the second assignment `TCNT1L=(-640);` depends on the assumption that the compiler will discard all bits above the 8 least significant bits. (Most (?) compilers (including avr-gcc I guess) will actually do exactly that but it's not guaranteed and implementation-dependent behavior AFAIK.)

Comment: In AVR, `TCNT1L` and `TCNT1H` are hardware addresses of 8-bit values. They are defined as uint8_t, so the idiom will work even without casting to uint8_t first.

Comment: Actually, now that I look closer, `-640` is not unintuitive. It is clear what is meant: The overflow interrupt occurs when the count on the clock, `TCNT`, rolls over to reach 0. The interrupt handler resets the count to -640 (or 2^16 - 640) so it will fire again after another 640 cycles. (You still get an upvote, though.)

Comment: Totally agree...it's actually quite elegant! I would have naively set `OCR1A` and used `TIMER1_COMPA_vect` (which would have been longer). thx for pointing that out!

Comment: i would also call this bad programming. To make this elegant you should hide the adding of the '-' and the cast to the proper Type in a macro. with some explaining comments.

Comment: @vega8 To me, the `OCR1A` approach is preferrable, because 1. that's one of the intended uses of the `OCR` interrupts and 2. `TCNT1` can be used for other purposes at the same time since `OCR1B` and the TOI can still be used independently (apart from the timer's frequency they all must share).